# Getting first word of file

Tags: text-processing

I am using below command to get first word of file

```
awk '{print $1}' myFile
```

but it is printing first word of all lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` will run the commands (except `BEGIN`/`END` blocks, etc.) on every line. So... exit after processing the first line:

```
awk '{print $1; exit}' /some/file
```

Or qualify to include only the first line:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {print $1}' /some/file #still runs the test on all lines
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` :

```
sed -nr '1s/^([^ ]+).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

- `1` at the start of the substitution pattern indicates that we are working only on the first line of the file
- `[^ ]+` will find the first space separated word, we are putting it into a group so that we can refer to it later in the substitution pattern
- `s/^([^ ]+).*/\1/` will replace the first line with only the first word

Answer (score 0):

Different approach without `awk` or `sed`:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < file.txt | head -n1
```